# Shouldn't it be "Milo Yiannopoulos–endorsing activists"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjective-phrases

I came across a sentence in a [fresh Buzzfeed article](https://www.buzzfeed.com/scaachikoul/california-college-republicans-milo-yiannopoulos-donald):

> At the California College Republicans Convention this spring, a war was brewing between loud, unapologetic, **Milo Yiannopoulos–endorsed activists** and moderate, policy-focused nerds. Guess who won?

I thought this is a mistake, because the context makes it clear that the article talks about students who support the conservative commentator Milo Yiannopoulos, not the other way around. Since a robber who brandishes a gun is a gun-brandishing robber, and a samurai who wields a sword is a sword-wielding samurai, shouldn't people who support Yiannopoulos be **Milo Yiannopoulos–endorsing activists**?

Comment: The sentence is right. Those who support him are activists in favor of MY. But here, he is the endorser, so to speak. So endorsed is correct. It means he has endorsed them.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it is as follows. *Endorsed activists* would be activists who are endorsed (supported) by some famous person (endorsement is typically something that a well-known person in a particular field does to help somebody who is not well-known receive more publicity). We need the past participle form of the verb *to endorse* to indicate that the act of endorsing is done for the activists. *Milo Yiannopoulos* in *Milo Yiannopoulos-endorsed activists* would then be describing the individual who is the source of their endorsement (support).

Since *endorsing* is the active form of the verb *to endorse*, *Milo Yiannopoulos–endorsing activists* sounds like it is the students who are actually endorsing Milo Yiannopoulos. As I mentioned a few lines above, endorsement is something that's typically done by a famous person or somebody whose opinion matters in a specific field and not by regular folks like you and me. That's actually the whole point of endorsement. If you are supported by somebody who is well-known or famous, people are going to listen to you. So, *Milo Yiannopoulos–endorsing activists* conceptually makes little sense. Why would a famous guy like Milo Yiannopoulos seek the support of a bunch of college students? It's them who actually need him because his fame can help them faster achieve their goal.

Comment: I found several sentences online: _Hoye’s office is a reminder that the city of Taunton is the other player that has been waiting for economic redemption after voters endorsed the tribal casino in a referendum in 2012._ (The Boston Globe, via Merriam Webster) _‘Cultural analysis lays bare how a fearful public passively endorses such measures because terrorist images allow ordinary people to detach themselves from the pain of their scapegoats by defining them as less than human.’_ (ODO) It seems *endorsement* doesn't have to top-down. The populace can also endorse.

Comment: Those are just other usages of the verb *to endorse*. In those sentences, it simply means *declare one's public approval or support of*. In a context where an organization or a person is being endorsed by somebody or some organization, it is typically implied that the person or the organization who is offering their endorsement are famous or well-known. And the person or the organization who is receiving endorsement is not widely known. That's actually the idea behind endorsement as it's used in the business of advertising and in the world of political campaigning.

Comment: For example, a celebrity like Arnold Schwarzenegger could endorse a bunch of animal rights activists that no one seems to know or care about. But, since it's Arnold Schwarzenegger himself who is giving them their support, people will listen to what he has to say and the activists will have a better chance of getting their ideas across to the general public. And the activists could then be referred to as Arnold Schwarzenegger-endorsed activists because they are the ones who are being endorsed and not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct that if it is the activists who endorse Milo Yiannopoulos, then that is an error, and it should read "Milo Yiannopoulos-endorsing activists".

It is, however, possible that Milo Yiannopoulos has been endorsing activists, in which case the phrase "Milo Yiannopoulos-endorsed activists" is correct.

Since I don't know which it is, I would take the headline at its word and assume that the author really does mean to say Milo Yiannopoulos has been endorsing activists, and these are some of them.